# Need "Missing source code" or similar option when marking question as unsalvageable in triage

Tags: feature-request, triage

In my review queue, I came across a question that was well written - user described the observed, vs desired behavior - except that the author had failed to include one of the source files/snippets that was in all likelihood the source of the problem (for example, included working HTML, but omitted CSS).

The question should be marked as "Unsalvageable", because it is unanswerable without the missing source, right? However none of the available reasons for flagging seem to describe this situation.

It's neither a duplicate, nor off-topic, nor unclear, nor too-broad, nor primarily opinion-based.

I suspect that others use the "unclear" option in cases like these, however, this option states,

> As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're
>   asking.

And if we tell that to the user, then we are misidentifying what's wrong with the question. In this case it IS clear what the user is asking, it's just not possible to answer. I need an option that says something like, "This question cannot be answered without additional information."

Comment: From should be closed->off-topic-> "...must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**."

Answer (score -7):

Perhaps make a comment that asks for the missing information?

Comment: Ideally you want to do both. Asking for the information is good, but if the question is unanswerable because it's lacking information, it should also be put on hold asap